# Discrepancy in Reflection of Auto-Incremented Value for Saved Records in JPA Repository

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have an entity class having the following field.

```
@Entity(name = "my_table")
public class MyTable {
   @Id
   @Column(name = "request_id", nullable = false)
   private String requestId;

   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY) // Auto-increment field
   @Column(name = "seq_id")
   private Long seqId;

   @Column(name = "customer_id", nullable = false)
   private String customerId;

}
```

I am saving this object using the following jpa repository to save it.

```
@Repository
public interface MyTableRepo extends JpaRepository<MyTable, String> {

     Optional< MyTable> findById(final String requestId);

 }
```

This is the service class for saving the object

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class MyTableService {
private final MyTableRepo myTableRepo;

@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
public MyTable save(final MyTable myTable){
    return myTableRepo.save(myTable);
}
```

calling save method to insert the data in the table

```
MyTable mytable = new Mytable();
mytable.setRequestId("someValue");
mytable.setCustomerId("123241");
 
myTableService.save(mytable);
mytable.getSeqId() // this gives null
```

After persisting a record using the JPA repository, I have observed that the record is successfully inserted into the table with the appropriate auto-incremented value. However, when retrieving the saved record using the associated entity object (e.g., mytable), the auto-incremented value is not being reflected.

I would appreciate any insights into the possible causes of this issue and guidance on potential solutions. How can I ensure that the auto-incremented value is correctly reflected in the associated entity object after saving a record using the JPA repository?

Answer (score 0):

`@GeneratedValue` can only be used with the ID column but now you are using it on the non-ID column and so it does not work.

There are [some discussion](https://github.com/jakartaee/persistence/issues/113) about making JPA to support it but as of today it is still not supported.

If you just need some unique identifier value for `seqId` , you could consider to use  `UUID` which can be easily generated manually by calling `UUID.toString()`.

If you really need it to be numeric , you can consider to use some distributed unique ID generator such as Snowflake. Some open source example can be found at [here](https://github.com/callicoder/java-snowflake) and [here](https://github.com/baidu/uid-generator).